# Nginx www to root redirection not working

Tags: django, linux, nginx, deployment

this is my nginx config

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///var/tmp/******.sock;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location /static {
        alias **********;
    }
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass ********;
        include *************;
    }

}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://mydomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

here mydomain is working fine

when i go to www.mydomain i am not getting redirected.

and lands on nginx default page.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed i just had to move the redirection server block before the root domain block